# Wilson's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help understanding Wilson's Theorem. I was reading a post on this [blog](http://theoremoftheweek.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/theorem-27-wilsons-theorem/) explaining this theorem.

$(p-1)! \equiv p -1 \bmod p$

$(p-1)! ≡ -1 \bmod p$

How is $p - 1 \pmod p$ equal to $-1 $?

Comment: We have $p-1\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, since the difference between the two numbers is divisible by $p$.

Comment: If p was 5, wouldn't (4-1) mod p be equal to 3? This is where I am confused.

Comment: Yes, (4-1) mod p would be equivalent to 3, but it would not be equivalent to (p-1) = (5-1), which is equivalent to both 4 and -1.

Comment: It is $4-(-1)=5$.

Comment: The point that might be troubling you is that in mathematics, $\ldots \equiv \ldots \mod p$ is a relation, not a function.  So $5 - 1 \equiv 4 \mod 5$ and $5 - 1 \equiv -1 \mod 5$ are both true statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ if and only if $m$ divides the difference $a-b$.

Let $a=p-1$, $b=-1$, $m=p$. 
Then $a-b=p-1-(-1)=p$. This is divisible by $p$.

In general, $p-a\equiv -a\pmod{p}$: same argument.

**Remark:** There are unfortunately two different but related uses of "mod." The first, wich was the first line of the answer, is the one primarily used in mathematics. The second, primarily used in computer science, is to write $a\bmod{m}=b$ if $b$ is the **remainder** when you divide $a$ by $m$. There is a relationship between the two notions:
$$a\equiv b\pmod{m}\quad\text{if and only if}\quad a\bmod{m}=b\bmod{m}.$$